# Is there a way to open a installed application on a Ipad?

Tags: ruby, appium

I have an iPad application that already installed on the device. But i don't have the **.app** or **.ipa** file with me.

Is there anyway to launch that application using Appium driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to automate a preinstalled app

This will only work for applications that are signed with a **DEVELOPMENT** cert.

This will **NOT** work for applications that are signed with a **DISTRIBUTION** cert (ex. apps downloaded from the App Store, distributed via Afaria or another MDM solution*)

You cannot automate applications downloaded from the above places. This is because Apple's Instruments will not allow you to inspect/interact with those applications. (Even if you somehow knew the bundleId)

---

1. Get the bundleId of the app that was installed on the device. Use that as the `app` capability.
2. Follow the Appium [Real Devices](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/appium-setup/real-devices.md) guide (substitute any `.ipa`/`.app` reference with the bundleId)

In addition to your regular `desiredCapabilities` (ex. `platformName`, `platformVersion`, `deviceName`).. these should be your `desiredCapabilities`:

```
// For preinstalled apps, this is the bundleId

desiredCaps['app'] = 'com.company.appname'

// The device's unique identifier.    
// Found in XCode's organizer when device is plugged in

desiredCaps['udid'] = '1824y983h2849gh2498'
```

* Barring TestFlight. If an app is uploaded via TestFlight, it may be signed with a Development or a Distribution certificate. You'll have to ask.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this information, just one doubt about it, here in this post [link](http://testdroid.com/tech/mobile-game-testing-part-2-ui-and-functionality-image-recognition) they are using Appium on a iPhone 4s using Clash of Clans which they do not own, any hints or ideas on how this is possible?

Comment: That's interesting. Instruments (what Appium uses to control iOS devices) prevents the installation of non-dev-signed apps. 

My guess is that iPhone 4S is jailbroken? or that they are on Clash of Clans' beta testers group and get access to a dev version. 

When I wrote this answer, I had just attempted to automate an enterprise-signed app for like ~4 hours and couldn't do it. When I realized that I could only do dev-signed apps, I resigned the app and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**

- *If you have created the app with a developer provisioning profile, and built yourself. Or downloaded it using testFlight, and is signed with a development provisioning profile*
- *You need to reference the app bundleID and the UDID of the device.  You then won't need the app path capability.*

**No**

- *If you have downloaded the app from the app store.*

Comment: Thanks @Neil. Unfortunately I don't have anything that mentioned in "Yes" section. My client is not ready share that information. Do you have another solution for it?

Comment: Unless you have development access to the application or devices assigned to the development version of the app, you cannot automate testing.

Comment: @NMKP the bundleId is not a secure piece of information. Ask them for it, or look for it yourself by connecting your device to XCode and then checking the Device's Applications using Organizer.